# how to replace a bearing on BB7800?

Tags: maintenance, bottom-bracket

Friends,

Do anyone of you know on how to replace a bearing on BB7800 ?
Do I need a special tool ? or a screw driver, and hammer would be enough to push it out ?

Thanks

Comment: The BB 7800 is a threaded BB cup. It cannot be "pushed" out without damaging the frame permanently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Park Tool web page](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/cartridge-bearing-type-bottom-bracket-service-bbt) shows the basic procedure.

You need the [BB cup tool](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/bottom-bracket-tool-selection) for that particular model of cartridge.

Comment: These tools, and that procedure are for the 7700 series Dura-Ace.

Answer (score 4):

The Dura-Ace BB-7800 is designed to be replaced as a cartridge unit. Replacing the bearing in the cup, without replacing the cup, would be difficult, if not impossible without damaging the cup.

These bottom brackets are exceptionally cheap, and really don't have much to them beyond the bearing, and the threaded cup to hold it in the frame.

Why spend the time and effort to replace only the bearing?

If you want to replace the whole cup cartridge, you need a [5mm allen key](http://www.parktool.com/product/5mm-p-handle-hex-wrench-ph-5), [a 3/8" drive torque wrench capable of 40Nm](http://www.parktool.com/product/ratcheting-click-type-torque-wrench-tw-6), [a 1/4" drive torque wrench capable of 12Nm](http://www.parktool.com/product/ratcheting-click-type-torque-wrench-tw-5), The [Shimano Hollowtech 2 BB cup tool](http://www.parktool.com/product/bottom-bracket-tool-BBT-19), and the [Hollowtech 2 BB bearing adjustment tool](http://www.parktool.com/product/adjusting-cap-tool-bbt-10).

Procedure [here from Shimano on PDF](http://www.shimano.com.au/publish/content/global_cycle/en/au/index/tech_support/tech_tips.download.-Par50rparsys-0003-downloadFile.html/Hollowtech%20II%20Crank%20Installation.pdf).

Video of general procedure [here](http://youtu.be/yiOqvoCJZfw).

Comment: I mean replacing the cartridge, is it possible ?

Comment: Yes it is. See edited info above. The link @DanielRHicks posted has the correct tools, if you scroll down, but the procedure is for the old 7700 Dura-Ace. Hope that helps.